# Input steppers placement in customer journey webshop

Tags: shopping-cart, b2b

I'm working on a B2B webshop where people can order products. They mostly order in quantities of 1-20 of the same product (we are talking about truck components).
The productoverview-page is the page where most people decide to place products in their shoppingcart. Right now we also show a input stepper so they can decide the quanitity. We haven't tracked this component to see if and how people are using it.

On a lot of B2C shops in my country I don't see a input stepper for quantity on the productoverview- or productdetail-page, only in the shoppingcart.

Do any of you have experience in where to place this input stepper and what arguments we can use where ever is best te place it (from a B2B perspective)?

Comment: If users tend to order the same item in bulk, keep the stepper both on the product page and in the cart/overview. 
On the product page, the stepper doesn't require additional clicks from users who are buying single items, but it makes the purchase a little easier for those who buy in bulk.

Comment: This sounds like a good case for an AB-test: 50% of the users have the bulk input in the product overview, the other 50% in the cart. Wouldn't surprise me if the results are almost even. People that remember the amount when they add the product have to keep that in memomry and go to the cart first before they can fill it in. People that forgot to fill in the amount while adding the product can still do that in the cart. Isn't there a possibilty to do both?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's great to have this quantity stepper n `Product Details` page and in the `Shopping cart`.

**One interesting example I saw:**

When you click add to cart

[image]

The buttons is transforming in the quantity stepper:

[image]

I would also consider adding suggested amounts under this quantity stepper if you start noticing patterns for specific products where customers are ordering in bulk amounts.

[image]